# How to use Dynamoid conditional range query with Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to use range query GT, LT, GTE in my application using rails 4.2 & dynamoid 1.3. It results nil value.

Gemfile

```
gem 'dynamoid', '1.3.0'
gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 2'
```

Config/initializers/dynamoid.rb

```
Dynamoid.configure do |config|
  config.access_key = '******************'
  config.secret_key = '**********************'
  config.region = 'us-east-1'
  config.adapter = 'aws_sdk_v2' 
  config.namespace = '***********' 
  config.warn_on_scan = true 
  config.read_capacity = 200
  config.write_capacity = 100
end
```

I am using for student table. below is my model class

```
class Student
  include Dynamoid::Document
  table :name => :students

  field :first_name
  field :age, :integer
end
```

When i am using below query it results NIL

```
Student.where(:"age.gt" => 2).all
```

Please suggest

Comment: Now such conditions work for any attribute

Answer (score 0):

The **range modifiers (gt, gte etc.)** can be used only when you have a range index.

**From docs:-**

> If you have a range index, Dynamoid provides a number of additional
> other convenience methods to make your life a little easier:
>
> User.where("created_at.gt" => DateTime.now - 1.day).all
> User.where("created_at.lt" => DateTime.now - 1.day).all
>
> It also supports .gte and .lte. Turning those into symbols and allowing a
> Rails SQL-style string syntax is in the works. You can only have one
> range argument per query, because of DynamoDB's inherent limitations,
> so use it sensibly!